# Taylor expansion with $o(x^{2n})$ or $o(x^{2n+1})$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I notice some books worte taylor expansion for Trigonometric and Hyperbolic functions with $o(x^{2n})$ or $o(x^{2n+1})$

for example

$$\cos \,x=\sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k}}{(2\,k)!}}+o(x^{2n})$$

and others

$$\cos \,x=\sum _{k=0}^{n }{(-1)^k\frac {x^{2k}}{(2\,k)!}}+o(x^{2n+1})$$

Could someone explain to me why

[image]

Comment: The term of order $2n+1$ is zero for $\cos$ as it has only even powers. Therefore, $o(x^{2n+1})$. Which is also, in particular, $o(x^{2n})$.

Comment: i see this is hold just for even and odd funcions  ? thanks

Comment: More general: it happens when $p_n(x)=p_{n+1}(x)$ in the expansion $f(x)=p_n(x)+o(x^n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Both are true, though the second formula says a little more. The next term in the Taylor expansion is $(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2}/(2n+2)!$, and so we see that the Taylor remainder term is $O(x^{2n+2})$ as $x\to 0$. But if the remainder term is $O(x^{2n+2})$ as $x\to 0$, then it is also $o(x^{2n+1})$ and $o(x^{2n})$.

Similar reasoning holds for the other asymptotic expressions: they are consequences of the big-O asymptotic expression for each Taylor approximation.

Comment: notice that i wrote them with small O not big one

Comment: Yes, I did notice that, and I have written my answer likewise to address that.

Comment: Educ: Your comment is disquieting and might indicate that you should revise thoroughly the definitions of O and o asymptotics.

Comment: @Did yes  i forgot this stuff i should make quick revise thanks for ur attention